# How to perform calculation

Tags: c#, math

I need to perform the following math operation in C#:
[image: Formula]

I tried to use the class [Matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix(v=vs.110).aspx) (System.Windows.Media), but I did not succeed

My Code:

```
    public double DegreeToRadian(double Degree)
    {
        return Degree * Math.PI / 180;
    }

    public double ToCotg(double Angle)
    {
        return (Angle < 0 ? -Math.PI / 2 : Math.PI / 2) - Math.Atan(Angle);
    }

    public List<double> YShear(double B, double X, double Y)
    {
        List<List<double>> Formula = new List<List<Double>>()
        {
            new List<double>(){ 1, 0, 0 },
            new List<double>(){ B, 1, 0 },
            new List<double>(){ 0, 0, 1 }
        };
        List<double> Multiplier = new List<double>() { X, Y, 1 };
        List<double> Result = new List<double>();

        foreach (List<Double> Matriz in Formula)
        {
            double Resultado = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Matriz.Count; i++)
            {
                double Value = Matriz[i];
                double Mutiply = Multiplier[i];
                Resultado += Value * Mutiply;
            }
            Result.Add(Resultado);
        }
        return Result;
    }


    public List<double> XShear(double A, double X, double Y)
    {
        List<List<double>> Formula = new List<List<Double>>()
        {
            new List<double>(){ 1, A, 0 },
            new List<double>(){ 0, 1, 0 },
            new List<double>(){ 0, 0, 1 }
        };
        List<double> Multiplier = new List<double>() { X, Y, 1 };
        List<double> Result = new List<double>();

        foreach (List<Double> Matriz in Formula)
        {
            double Resultado = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < Matriz.Count; i++)
            {
                double Value = Matriz[i];
                double Mutiply = Multiplier[i];
                Resultado += Value * Mutiply;
            }
            Result.Add(Resultado);
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

Code test:

```
        double Angle = 30f; // 30º
        double Radians = DegreeToRadian(Angle);
        double X = 30;
        double Y = 30;
        double Cotg = ToCotg(Radians);
        double ResultX = X + Cotg * Y; // (MBo code) Result: 30
        double ResultY = Y + Cotg * X; // (MBo code) Result: 30
        XShear(Cotg, X, Y); // 62,6534525908162, 30, 1
        YShear(Cotg, X, Y); // 62,6534525908162, 30, 1
```

Expected result: 
XShear with 30º = (~46, 30, 1) and YShear with 30º = (30, ~46)

Comment: Can you please share the code you've written so far even if it is giving wrong output.

Comment: I do not have the code anymore, because I was trying to do it manually (applying the formula and multiplying the column one by one), but I did not succeed in that way. When trying to use the Matrix class I could not insert a 3x3 array as the formula asks, only one of 3x2.

Comment: In this representation of affine transformations, the bottom row is always `[0,0,1]`, so there are only 6 (not 9) degrees of freedom. For this reason, the constructor for the class that you link to takes 6 doubles. Perhaps you can look at the documentation more carefully.

Comment: I edited the post. I inserted a code that I made here, but that presents an error in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Function `ToCotg` expects arguments in radians (it uses Math.PI constant and Math.Atan function), while you call it with 30 degrees value.

Use function like `ToRadians` if available or just multiply degrees by `Math.PI / 180`

2) Function `ToCotg` is wrong - you subtract atan value from angle. Right pseudocode:

```
if Angle = 0 or Angle = Math.Pi  // if Sin(Angle) = 0
  return Infinity  //extra case
else
  return 1.0 / Math.Tan(Angle)
```

3) What angle is used for Y_Shear? If 30 degrees between OX and tilted edge,  then B=Tan(30)

4) Why not use simple formulas like

```
Result.X = X + A * Y
Result.Y = Y

Result.X = X
Result.Y = Y + B * X
```

for XShear and YShear to avoid excessive calculations (in any case you don't exploit universal subroutines like vector*matrix multiplication)

Paper-and-pen calculations for theta as drawn at the picture:

```
 Cotan(30) = 1.73
 X after XShear = 30 +  1.73 * 30 = 81.96
```

Comment: I made the changes and inserted the new results into the post, I also did a little test with your idea of code, but it did not work either.

Comment: @Victor Magalhães  I missed mistake inside cotg function. See edit.

Comment: I made changes to the code, but is this result correct? I used as a reference the results obtained in Paint. With 30º the correct result would not be ~46?

Comment: @Victor Magalhães Probably you consider another (complement) angle 60 degrees. For that angle X becomes 47.3. Note that 30 degrees is rather acute angle and X shifts at large distance.

Comment: Somehow the result is half or double the test with the paint, but maybe it's the way the paint evaluates the calculation, but it's good for me. Thank you very much for the help!